# If value contains these letters, then

Tags: sql-server, regex, if-statement

In SQL Server, is there a way to search (and format) a result for a certain string (like `preg_match` in PHP):

```
SELECT (IF (col1 contains 'http'){'<a>' + col 1 + '</a>'}
else {'<b>' + col1 + '</b>'}),
col2
FROM Table
```

... etc.

Is this possible? I want to format the results based on their content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%http%' THEN '<a>' + col1 + '</a>' ELSE '<b>' + col1 + '</b>' END AS 'Desired Column Name', col2
FROM table
```

See the MSDN Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Thank you! One quick question, how can I make it so that first column shows a column name. As it is, it works, but shows 'no column name' for the first column. I'm assuming I have to add 'as col1' somewhere?

Comment: You need to add the "AS 'col1'" after the "END" part

Comment: Great, thank you daz-fuller, thank you Dommer, thank you SO :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (from the AdventureWorks database)

```
SELECT  Title,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        CASE 
            WHEN LastName LIKE 'G%' THEN '<a href="mailto:' + EmailAddress + '">' + LastName + '</a>'
            ELSE '<b>' + LastName + '</b>'
        END
FROM    SalesLT.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following:

```
IF (my_column_name LIKE "%MATCHSTRING%", 1, 0) AS new_column_name,
```

Leave off the % if you are doing a exact match as opposed to a contains